# What are the pros and cons for using a IOC container?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Using a IOC container will decrease the speed of your application because most of them uses reflection under the hood. They also can make your code more difficult to understand(?). On the bright side; they help you create more loosely coupled applications and makes unit testing easier. Are there other pros and cons for using/not using a IOC container?

Answer (score 19):

If you're using an IOC container in a simple fashion, reflection is only used on startup - the application is wired up to start with, and then it runs as normal without any intervention from the container. Of course, if you're using the IOC to resolve dependencies after you've started running, that may be slightly different - although I'd still expect it to resolve lazily and cache unless you've got it configured to create new instances each time.

As for making the code harder to understand - quite the reverse! With the dependencies explicitly stated, it's much easier to understand each component, and the configuration file(s) make it clear how the whole application hangs together.

Comment: Once you are using an IoC container, the code is easier to understand. However, before they use it, it can be hard for some developers to understand why they need one. The problems of complexity that it solves are not generally present in toy applications.

Comment: I agree and disagree: The independent fragments are easier to understand in isolation. But the whole picture and wiring is more dificuilt. Example: You are reading the sourcecode of a service that calls a repository-save method. I you ask your editor "goto definition of save" you end up in the interface definition but not in the concrete implementation used.

Comment: @k3b: Sure, so you need to have a view of the plumbing as well... but I don't think that's enough of an impediment to make it worth tightly coupling different services to each other.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know it's an old question and comment but: it's not "either IoC or tightly coupled". To put it simply, we can have properly modular code, and be in control of the branching.

Answer (score 7):

Well I suppose a con I've experienced is that some developers don't seem to be able to grasp IoC. We've had a few people who were against it for no reason other than that they didn't understand them. (Not saying that's a bad reason to be against something, not at all.)

It does add a bit of abstraction that always seems to manage to confuse someone or other, but I'd say the pros far outweigh the cons in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is fair to say if you have expert understanding of how to use IOC and tend to write good code anyway, then IOC will make your code easier to understand on all but the smallest systems.

However if you are working somewhere where most classes/methods are very large and the concept of refactoring has not yet taken hold, then trying to use an IOC is likely just to make the software harder to understand.  The IOC also has to be leant by everyone that programs on the project, so that may be a consideration.

I see IOC as icing on the cake; I like the icing but only on a nice cake.  If the cake is not nice to start with, sort out the cake first.

As to the performance overhead of using IOC, I don’t see this as a problem in most cases.  The overhead need not be large, and given the speed of today’s CPU most of you run time is likely to be data access anyway.  If a IOC proved to slow for a given bit of code I would look at adding some caching of returned object, or removing the IOC *just* from that bit of code.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the assumption about reduced execution speed is much the same kind of argument as "C is faster than C#/Java". While this statement *may* be true for specific operations and/or structurally simple tasks it is not the case the moment complexity rises.

The way DI-frameworks let you focus on object creation and dependencies creates more efficient systems when code size increases. For large applications I'm almost certain DI-framework based code will outperform any alternative solution. There's simply so little redundancy in the runtime that it's hard to make it more efficient! Most of the additional overhead is also just at first load.

Advanced DI containers also lets you do "scope" magic that you can only dream of without the container. Using scope-proxies, [spring](http://www.springsource.org/) can do the following:

```
 A Singleton
 |
 B Singleton
 |
 C Prototype (per-invocation)
 |
 D Singleton
 |
 E Session scope (web app)
 |
 F Singleton
```

Effectively you can have ten layers of singleton objects and all of a sudden something session scoped shows up.

Stuff like security can be injected in totally different manner than you would otherwise. There's often a classical paradox: Often the GUI layer needs to have intricate knowledge of the security permissions. Quite often the services layer also needs this, but often at a different level of detail (usually less detailed than the gui). The classical approach would be to send it around as parameters, put it on a threadlocal or to ask a service. With spring you can just inject it straght where you need it and no-one else needs to know.

This actually changes application development as a whole. I had a real hard time adjusting to this, but after this pain I see it is truly a lot closer to how things should be (as opposed to how we've learned to do it).

So I think DI frameworks have the potential of changing the way you make programs, with much further reaching implications than just DI. It's not just a glorified way of calling **new**.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the answers so far.

What I'd like to add, is that it creates a bit of overhead, so it isn't really suited for small applications.

Mid-size and larger applications benefit the most from using IoC.

You might also check out this question for more information on pros and cons: [Castle Windsor Are There Any Downsides?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388355/castle-windsor-are-there-any-downsides)

Answer (score 2):

In most circumstances you would not even notice performance penalty since for "singleton" objects all the initialization is performed once only. I would also argue that IoC makes it different to understand the code: on the contrary, IoC-style development forces you to create small coherent classes, which are in turn easier to grok.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a business application, using an inversion-of-control and dependency-injection container (in conjunction with other agile practices and tools) will help you out in terms of productivity and reliability.

Moreover, your application will probably spend a vast majority of its CPU time waiting for resources or waiting for human interaction and doing nothing useful. Your application should have plenty of horsepower to spare for a few microseconds of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It seeks to reduce their dependency with IOC by ensuring object instance management within the application. The framework, rather than the developer, is in charge of creating and managing dependencies in your project.

The framework calls and runs our code when we write a block of code, and the entire event of passing control back to the framework is known as the Inversion of Control.

- It enables the execution of a method separate from its
  implementation.
- It enables you to switch between multiple implementations with ease.
- increases the modularity of the software
- Because dependencies are reduced, it is simple to test and write.