# Any IOC framework to recommend under c# 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, inversion-of-control

I am wondering if anyone can recommend IOC framework which can work under c# 4.0? Also, does .Net framework 4.0 natively support IOC?

Comment: Subjective question. Everyone will just answer with their favorite IoC. Either add specific requirements that it must support or delete the question.

Comment: Need to support .Net Framework, better can be configured using both XML and attributes

Comment: All of the answers you get is for .Net. 99% of all frameworks support xml/attributes. You could have found that by googling. Those requirements are therefore not very specific.

Comment: Has been asked many times before, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216684/comparing-castle-windsor-unity-and-structuremap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148908/which-dependency-injection-tool-should-i-use

Comment: IoC is "natively supported" in the sense that you don't need a framework in any language to use it. It's just a concept. You can implement your own dependency injection.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Hanselman has a list of .Net IOC/Dependency injection tools here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

and there are some good feature charts to be found here:

http://code.google.com/p/net-ioc-frameworks/wiki/Charts

Otherwise it's simply down to requirement & personal preference (Ninject/StructureMap in my case!)

Answer (score 1):

[MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) can be used as an IoC and is part of the .Net 4 framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216565/why-exactly-isnt-mef-a-di-ioc-container